# How to create a relative symlink which works across PC

Tags: symlink

I have the following directory structure to start with

```
~/a/bin
~/a/src -> /home/user/b/sync/src
```

I created a symlink

```
cd ~/a/src
ln -s ../bin bin-xyz
```

now bin-xyz is a broken link, and there is no way of cd-ing into it.

**What i am looking for?**

How to create a symlink inside a symlinked folder such that the relative path is not broken. For example,

```
 cd ~/a/src/bin-xyz
```

or

```
 cd ~/b/sync/src/bin-xyz
```

should work provided that there is bin directory in ~/a/ or ~b/sync/

**Why i am looking for this ?**

I am syncing ~/b/sync/src across machines, where ~/a/ is my workspace in both the machines but the user name of the machines differ. So, having a relative path that works means an easier work-flow for me.

I am using bittorent sync for syncing.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> now bin-xyz is a broken link

The reason for that is hopefully obvious: Either `..` has to refer to the *actual* parent directory or else it would be completely ambiguous.

Since `~/a/src -> /home/user/b/sync/src`, I presume with that as `$PWD` and `ln -s ../bin bin-xyz` you're trying to link `/home/user/b/sync/src/bin-xyz` to `/home/user/a/sync/bin`.  In which case you should just use absolute paths:

```
 ln -s /home/user/a/sync/bin /home/user/b/sync/src/bin-xyz
```

The reason `ln` doesn't fill in the `..` blanks in this regard is that it, unlike your current shell, has not been tracking your movement and has no way to know that by `..` you meant something other than the real parent directory.

It's (maybe?) implied in your question that you can't do this because there are actually two different systems involved.  That implies either a network share is mounted or you use the same block device with both, implying in turn an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- can't solve that without more details.

Comment: there is no special networking issue.  Anyways, thanks for your comment i have been able to resolve it by `ln -s ../../../a/bin bin-xyz` now the symlink file can be synced and still work on my other machine. As my directory structure ,at the user level, in both the machines is the same.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as `ln -s  /home/user/a/sync/bin bin-xyz`?  If this is just one drive and no networking is involved, what is the issue with the "two machines"? I'm confused as to why you think you need to use a relative `..` path.

Comment: i wanted to use relative path because the user names in the two machines, that i sync, differ. And what i meant by "there is no special networking issue" is that, there is no share mount or usage of the same block device which were suggest in the answer above.